# Django view function does not seem to work

Tags: django, django-views

Here are you 2 functions in my django views. 
The first one and the second should do the same thing. But when I used the first function, it says "outside function" on the last line, which is "return HttpResponse(output)".

Why is that?

Thanks,
Shiyam

```
def main_page(request):
    output = '''
        <html>
            <head><title>%s</title></head>
            <body>
                <h1>%s</h1><p>%s</p>
            </body>
        </html>
    ''' % (
        'Django Learning',
        'Welcome',
        'WYou can share book marks here!'
)
return HttpResponse(output)

def main_page(request):
    title_sowl = "Django Learning"
    header_sowl = "Welcome"
    text_sowl = "You can share book marks here"
    output = u"<html><head><title>%s</title></head><body><h1>%s</h1><p>%s</p></body></html>" % (title_sowl,header_sowl,text_sowl)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Comment: You need to indent (tab) one more level the first return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you need to indent that line in order for it to be considered a part of the `main_page` method.

Comment: Thanks ryuusenshi Cesar. I don't know how I missed it. 
Cesar,
I am not sure how I can mark you as useful answer because it is a comment. If you know a way, i am happy to mark it foryou

Comment: Don't worry, it's okay. I'm glad it helped